# Digit recognizion of non light/color digits using Python/OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-recognition, digits

I am using OpenCV 4 and latest Python version. Got all the packages aswell.

I know how to resize, grayscale, blur, edge etc, but I get so many errors, seems like I cant get any detection.

Here is the Multimeter display image which is cropped which I am trying to detect and extract the digits from.

I need a simple code or help to code and to retrieve the digits, tried multiple guides without success. OpenCV is new to me, but took me 2-3 days to learn the basic image processing capabilities.

Digital multimeter non color

[image]

Ok, Now I have updated the code. I want to extract the digits from the warped and transformed binary image. But I get either errors or I need to delete parts of the code in order to at least show me the two images.
Here is the code so far:

```
# import the necessary packages
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
from imutils import contours
import imutils
import cv2

# define the dictionary of digit segments so we can identify
# each digit on the thermostat
DIGITS_LOOKUP = {
(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1): 0,
(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0): 1,
(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0): 2,
(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1): 3,
(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0): 4,
(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1): 5,
(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1): 6,
(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0): 7,
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1): 8,
(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1): 9}

# load the example image
image = cv2.imread("Multimeter_1.jpg")

# pre-process the image by converting it to
# graycale, blurring it, and computing an edge map
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7,7), 0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, 
cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,87,9)


# find contours in the edge map,
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

rect = None
# loop over the contours
for c in cnts:
# approximate the contour
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
#cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (36, 255, 12), 1)
cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12),3)
rect = c

peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)

if len(approx) == 4:
    rect = approx
    break


# extract the display, apply a perspective transform

warped = four_point_transform(thresh, rect.reshape(4, 2))
output = four_point_transform(image, rect.reshape(4, 2))

# Warp the image and perform morphology to clean it

thresh = cv2.threshold(warped, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU) 
[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)


# pre-process the image by converting it to
# graycale, blurring it, and computing an edge map
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7,7), 0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, 
cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,87,9)


# find contours in the edge map,
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

rect = None
# loop over the contours
for c in cnts:
# approximate the contour
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
#cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (36, 255, 12), 1)
cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12),3)
rect = c

peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)

if len(approx) == 4:
    rect = approx
    break


# extract the display, apply a perspective transform

warped = four_point_transform(thresh, rect.reshape(4, 2))
output = four_point_transform(image, rect.reshape(4, 2))
# Warp the image and perform morphology to clean it

thresh = cv2.threshold(warped, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU) 
[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (1, 5))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

cnts = 
cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
digitCnts = []

# loop over the digit area candidates
for c in cnts:
(x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)

# if the contour is sufficiently large, it must be a digit
if w >= 25 and (h >= 50 and h <= 60):
digitCnts.append(c)


cv2.imshow("Multimeter", image)
cv2.imshow("Multimeter2", thresh)


cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Warped,Transformed, tresholded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmowK.jpg)

Comment: Please provide samples of the code you have tried - that will make it easier for people to respond to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cv2.adaptiveThreshold()` to get a binary image then extract the display by sorting for the largest contour. Once you have detected this contour, you can then apply your perspective transformation

[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7,7), 0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,87,9)

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

rect = None
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 3)
    # cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (36, 255, 12), 1)
    rect = c
    break

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Ok, super thanks for your help nathanacy, so now I have found the contours and performed a perspective transform. How do I proceed? Need to treshold again, make contours where the actual digits and extract them?

Comment: After perspective transforming, I would threshold again then perform morphological operations to extract each digit

Comment: Don't edit answers as an attempt to reply. Use the comment section or edit your own post

Comment: As you see from my above and updated code. I need help to actually detect the digits now, that means draw a bounding box,then extract them and print out the detected digits to an image or to console.

Answer (score 0):

I struggle to write a correct code for that, still in learning process...

I took that morphed image and made another python script to simplify things. Now lets say the image is already binary, transformed and warped. How can I detect the digits and display the information on the image or on console after extraction? I have not learned to do that yet. I struggle to find the coordinates of the digits, I just found the rectangle boundry of the image it self but not what I am looking for.

In other words: I need help to find the boundry boxes first of the digits, detect and extract them.

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Pzu.jpg)

Here is simplified sample code so far:

```
# import the necessary packages
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
from imutils import contours
import imutils
import cv2
import numpy

image = cv2.imread("Morph.jpg")
copy = image.copy()
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cnts = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

ROI_number = 0
for c in cnts:
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
cv2.rectangle(copy,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(36,255,12),2)
ROI_number += 1



cv2.imshow('thresh', image)
cv2.imshow('copy', copy)
cv2.imwrite("Morphed_rectangle.jpg",copy)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: So, how do I extract the digits from the binary image and code above? Anyone has any tips? I use the latest OpenCV and python